# Catalog product page gives error 500 after upgrade from 1.7.3 to 1.7.6

Tags: prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-1.7

I can't access the product catalog page or edit any products after upgrading from 1.7.3.1 to 1.7.6.1

It gives me two fatal php errors.

The first exception: Twig\Error\RuntimeError

in src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/layout.html.twig (line 34)

```
    layoutHeaderToolbarBtn is defined ? layoutHeaderToolbarBtn : [],

    layoutDisplayType is defined ? layoutDisplayType : '',

    showContentHeader is defined ? showContentHeader : true,

    headerTabContent is defined ? headerTabContent : '',

    enableSidebar is defined ? enableSidebar : false,

Line 34  help_link is defined ? help_link : ''

  )

  )) %}

{% import '@PrestaShop/Admin/macros.html.twig' as ps %}
```

The second exception: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

```
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php (line 348)

            if ($lev <= \strlen($id) / 3 || false !== strpos($knownId, $id)) {

                $alternatives[] = $knownId;

            }

        }

        throw new ServiceNotFoundException($id, null, null, $alternatives);

    }[enter image description here][1]

}

/**

 * Returns true if the given service has actually been initialized.
```

Cross posted here https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1003821-catalog-product-page-gives-error-500-after-upgrade-from-173-to-176/

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRgtC.png)

Comment: try to remove all files in /var/cache/dev and in /var/cache/prod also delete /app/cache/dev and /app/cache/prod

Comment: Hello, i Already tried this without luck, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that the related products module was not updated. It's a module bought on the Marketplace. I checked the compatibility and it said it was compatible with 1.7.6.1, so for that reason, combined with my backoffice telling me i had 0 available updates and that the module was up to date, i assumed it was all good.

But apparently, modules bought on the marketplace, don't have their updates show up in prestashop.

I fixed the issue, by uninstalling the related products module and downloading the newest one 1.6.4 instead of 1.6.3 from the prestashop marketplace.